# How do I create a two way binding list of elements consisting of input boxes using AlpineJs

Tags: javascript, alpine.js, 2-way-object-databinding

I need to create a list of input boxes based on a array element. However when using x-for for looping and x-model for binding the elements any changes to the input boxes are not transmitted back to the original array.

```
    <div x-data="{items: ['apples','pears']}">

    <h3>List of items:</h3>

    <template x-for="item in items">
        <div>
            <input class="text" x-model="item"></input>
        </div>
    </template>
    <br>
    <button @click="items.push('')">+</button>
    <br>
    <span x-text="items"></span>

    </div>
```

How do I fix this to achieve 2-way data binding so that any changes to the input boxes also updates the items array.

Comment: After everything I tried it seems that Alpine does _not_ like binding directly to an array numeral (`items.0`). Binding to `item` has no value since it's only a value returned from a for loop. If you explain what your use case for this is, perhaps I can help you find a workable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```html
<div x-data="{items: ['apples','pears']}">

    <h3>List of items:</h3>

    <template x-for="(item, i) in items">
        <div>
            <input class="text" x-model="items[i]">
        </div>
    </template>

    <br>

    <button @click="items.push('')">+</button>

    <br>

    <span x-text="items"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Damn it's actually so simple! I was trying to figure this one out but I guess I was overthinking the whole process!